# My java code keep giving me Exceptions. How do i prevent this exception when i type the word stop?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

public class BoxOfficeImproved {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
            String inData;
            int age;
            for (;;) {
            System.out.println("Enter your age:");
            inData = stdin.nextLine();
            age = Integer.parseInt(inData); // convert inData to int

            if (inData.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop")) {
                System.exit(1);
            } else {

                if (age <= 17) {
                    System.out.println("Child Rate");

                    if (age < 5) {
                        System.out.println("30 Percent discount from child rate");

                    }
                } else if (age > 70) {

                    System.out.println("25 Percent discount from Adult Rate");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Adult rate");
                }

                System.out.println("Enjoy the show"); // always executed


        }
    }
}

}
```

error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "stop"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at BoxOfficeImproved.main(BoxOfficeImproved.java:14)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Comment: `age = Integer.parseInt(inData); // convert inData to int` How would you convert `stop` to an `int`?

Comment: As exception says `stop` is not an integer and its word which can't be parsed by `Integer.parseInt()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Don't parse age as int until you're sure you have a number input.

Ugly code; hard to read.  Learn the Sun Java coding standards and develop a rigorous, consistent style for brace placements.  IDEs can help with this.

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

public class BoxOfficeImproved {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inData;
        int age;
        for (;;) {
        System.out.println("Enter your age:");
        inData = stdin.nextLine();

        if (inData.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop")) {
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            age = Integer.parseInt(inData); // convert inData to int
            if (age <= 17) {
                System.out.println("Child Rate");

                if (age < 5) {
                    System.out.println("30 Percent discount from child rate");

                }
            } else if (age > 70) {

                System.out.println("25 Percent discount from Adult Rate");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Adult rate");
            }

            System.out.println("Enjoy the show"); // always executed


    }
}
}

}
```

Here's another idea on how to write it.  I think it's more extensible and less verbose:

```
/**
 * A better box office
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 11/17/2014
 * Time: 1:47 PM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979396/my-java-code-keep-giving-me-exceptions-how-do-i-prevent-this-exception-when-i-t/26979452#26979452
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BoxOfficeImproved {

    private static Map<Integer, String> OUTCOMES;

    static {
        OUTCOMES = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>() {{
            put(5, "30 Percent discount from child rate");
            put(17, "Child Rate");
            put(71, "Adult rate");
            put(1000, "25 Percent discount from Adult Rate");
        }};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inData;
        int age;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter your age:");
            inData = stdin.nextLine();
            try {
                age = Integer.parseInt(inData);
                System.out.println(getOutcome(age));
                System.out.println("Enjoy the show"); // always executed
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(String.format("'%s' is not a valid age; try again", inData));
            }
        } while (!"stop".equalsIgnoreCase(inData));
    }

    public static String getOutcome(int age) {
        for (int minAge : OUTCOMES.keySet()) {
            if (age < minAge) {
                return OUTCOMES.get(minAge);
            }
        }
        return String.format("No outcome found for age %d", age);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse `inData` as an integer before you check if it is the word "Stop". Trying to parse "Stop" as an integer raises an exception. Try parsing *after* the check instead.

```
inData = stdin.nextLine();
if (inData.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop")) {
    System.exit(1);
} else {
    age = Integer.parseInt(inData);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You convert the inputed string to an `int` **before** checking it isn't the word "stop" - this should be done only once you've decided you don't want to stop:

```
inData = stdin.nextLine();
if (inData.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop")) {
    System.exit(1);
} else {
    age = Integer.parseInt(inData); // convert inData to int
    // rest of the code to handle age
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the parse statement(`Integer.parseInt(inData)`) in your else block.

```
if (inData.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop")) {
                System.exit(1);
            } else {
        age = Integer.parseInt(inData); 
        System.out.println("Child Rate");
```